# Can I replace a dual section capacitor in a tube amplifier design with two single capacitors?

Tags: capacitor, amplifier, audio, vintage

[image]

I was planning on building this schematic, but found it hard to source their 20/20 dual section cap (C3/C4). Could I replace this with two single 20uF caps, or is it a dual-section for a reason?

Comment: Depending on how authentic you want to go with this design you could also replace the rectifier tube (V4) with just 2 diodes.  Just be sure they are rated for more than the expected current and voltage.

Comment: Note the rectifier tube provides some tone shaping, since it has voltage sag under heavier loads. A modern diode will be a very consistent drop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the C3/4 designator, since I assume you are asking about that?

Historically since large caps came in sockets it was more convenient. Nowadays that design would be 2 discrete capacitors. I see no issue with what you are considering.

Comment: I've never seen large electrolytics in a socket in equipment going back to the 1920s. In earlier ones they often had a bolt to mount them to the chassis, on later ones they had twist tabs.

Comment: This was very popular in radios etc. I guess by large I'm not talking huge chassis mount. I'm talking about larger then typical signal conditioning capacitors.

Answer (score 0):

Two 22\$\mu\$F caps; just be sure they're rated for sufficient voltage.  You'll find them to be smaller than the old-style caps, too.

Answer (score -1):

Seperate Electrolytic Caps are fine for Servicing replacements .Multisection caps where the negative was common were normal        in the Valve era but were not in 
 seen   the solid state era.I have replaced multisection electros with seperate caps for 40 years with no problems.